# Including /excluding an include statement based on the value of a variable

Tags: php

On an index page, I have this:

```
 include "commentformonoff.php";
```

I would like to modify it so that this inclusion is only done if a variable `$countcomments` is equal to 99 or less.  If `$countcomments` is equal to 100 or more, I would like to echo a message that says "Comments closed."

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this condition inline in a php script? If it is, then perhaps you should consider switching to using a templating system (such as smarty, or the more php-styled phpsavant)?  This will make such conditions much easier to manage in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($countcomment < 100)
{
   include "commentformonoff.php";
} else {
   echo "Comments Closed";
}
```

Comment: Further reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php